# Multiple custom views in Sherlock Action Bar ..?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I need multiple custom views in action bar. (Since menu items cannot be aligned left).

I did try to do that but it only shows one view at a time. Is it even possible..?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need multiple custom views? You can put many buttons in one custom view.